# Formatting with fancyhdr

Tags: formatting, header-footer, titles, fancyhdr, geometry

I need a special formatting for my document which it class is (`article`).

1. The first page has:

   - special header and NO footer
   - header contains image on the right and text on the left and both on the same level
   - Text in the center of the page

   I need to customize the header height.
2. The rest of the document:

   - NO header (the text start from the begging of the page )
   - page number on the header left

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\thispagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{ SOME TEXT }

\rhead{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{IMG}}

\centering

\vspace * {\fill}

SOME TEXT

\vspace * {\fill}

\end{titlepage}

TEXT TEXT TEXT ....

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for my question, here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[margin=2.1cm,headheight=18pt]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{titlepage}

\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{TEXT}
\rhead{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{IMG}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\rfoot{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}

\centering
\vspace * {\fill}
    TEXT
\vspace * {\fill}

\end{titlepage}


\newpage
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\thepage} 

TEXT TEXT TEXT 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmm, your original request was for page numbers in the footer, but your answer has the page numbers in the header.

Comment: @Werner You are right. But during the formatting I just think it would be better if I add it on the top , and it is easy to change it to the footer center.  Anyway it is not a big deal :). Thank you Werner.